# what is a good way to study for the tech test

Tags: united-states, license

I took the test last week but I failed it I was in a program that went through all the chapters but I just very bad at taking tests is there a way to go around the test

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered taking practice exams?  Consider the following link which is a set of practice exams that iterate through the question pool on subsequent retakes of the test.  Exam link: [QRZ Practice Ham Tests](https://www.qrz.com/hamtest/)

I would suggest you consider the following method:
(1) answer questions you are confident in knowing the right answer.
(2) research other areas until you understand the material gaining the confidence in the material.

For the second part, some times the correct answer is just common sense based on knowing the FCC regulations.  Don't guess on these, try to understand why that answer is the correct one.

Continue retaking the practice exams using a method like that outlined above until you score 100 percent over and over again.

Comment: Practice practice practice! Pretty much what my then-13-year-old son did to pass the Tech test.

Answer (score 1):

No way around it, you have to earn it. It's easy. Just takes a little time and dedication. Repetition of practice tests, study the questions with the correct answers.  If you don't understand the question or the reason for that answer, google it.  There are apps for your smart phone as well as internet websites. www.eham.net/exams  hamstudy.org  arrlexamreview.appspot.com  When you are getting 85-90% on the practice exams you will pass the official exam. My point is, if you are bad at taking tests then practice taking the test.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking if you can get an amateur radio license without passing the test. Sorry, the answer to that is no.

Having said that, there are ways to take the test if one has special needs such as a physical handicap or perhaps something like dyslexia. The VEC that administered your test --or the ARRL-- should be able to provide you with such exceptions to a regular written exam, such as giving you the test orally.

Answer (score 0):

Many people initially fail the test. Some fail it several times. You can keep trying.

Most "study" guides and apps simply give you the questions and tell the correct answer. For tech there is a pool of about 350 questions. Its actually fewer, but 350 is close enough. With enough repetition you will eventually memorize enough of the answers to pass the test.

Other guides and training material will teach you the material. For example how to use Ohm's law to calculate current when voltage and resistance are known. Many people do better when they understand how to get the answers instead of just memorizing the answers.

For some questions like questions on regulations, the only practical way to do it to memorize the answers.

The test material is grouped by subjects. Most practice tests will show which subjects you are having trouble with and which subject you are doing good in. Focus on the subjects you are having trouble with.

I use a exam practice app on the iphone. There are many of them available in the app store, most are free. do a few practice tests each day until you are pass most of them. The you will be ready to test.

If you get a exam preparation book from your library, make sure it is current. The tests are revised every 5 years. They don't change all of the questions, but they do change some of them.

I am a part of volunteer examiner group that gives the tests. We had a mother and son come in to test and both failed. Talking to them, they had used a book from their local library that was 15 or 20 years old.

Study and practice, you can pass the test. .